# Nesting Angular Expressions

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to **AngularJS** and I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding how to get functionality similar to nesting Angular expressions (i.e. if `{{ {{ variable }} }}` were considered legal syntax).

I want to store the name of controller-scoped variables (`foo`, `bar`) in a separate controller-scoped variable (`myCondition`) and I want to be able to pass the evaluation of `myCondition` to a directive and have its evaluation then be evaluated as `{{foo}} --> outcomeFoo` or `{{bar}} --> outcomeBar` within the template.

After reading a lot of solutions for similar problems online, I've tried variations of:

- `{{$eval(condition)}}`
- `{{scope.$eval(condition)}}`
- `{{scope.$parent.$eval(condition)}}`

and

- `condition: '@myDirective'` / `<p my-directive="{{myCondition}}">`
- `condition: '=myDirective'` / `<p my-directive="myCondition">`
- `condition: '&myDirective'` / `<p my-directive="myCondition">`

and I still can't figure it out where I'm going wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  $scope.myCondition = "foo";

  $scope.foo = "outcomeFoo";
  $scope.bar = "outcomeBar";
});

myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      condition: '@myDirective'
    },
    template: function(scope, attrs) {
      return 'Condition "{{condition}}" evalutes as, {{$eval(condition)}}.'
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">

<body ng-controller="myController">
  <p my-directive="{{myCondition}}"></p>
</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

### Edit (Solution)

Is solved by adding `controller: 'myController',` to the directive, such that it reads:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    controller: 'myController',
    scope: {
      condition: '@myDirective'
    },
    template: function(scope, attrs) {
      return 'Condition "{{condition}}" evalutes as, {{$eval(condition)}}.'
    }
  };
});
```

This will provide an output of,

> Condition "foo" evalutes as, outcomeFoo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure this is what you are after, but this works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <title>AngularJS Example</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

    myApp.controller('appController', function($scope) {
      $scope.myCondition = "foo";
    });


    myApp.controller('myController', function($scope) {
      $scope.values = {
        foo: "outcomeFoo",
        bar: "outcomeBar"
      };
    });


    myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
      return {
        controller: 'myController',
        scope: {
          condition: '@myDirective'
        },
        template: 'Condition "{{condition}}" evalutes as, {{values[condition]}}.'
      };
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="appController">
    <p my-directive="{{myCondition}}"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

What I am doing is providing an unique controller for the app and a second controller for the directive. The directive's controller has an object that includes the values for `foo` and `bar`. This way you can use the `condition` as a key into the `$scope.values` object.

Of course this will fail if you pass in a condition that does not match a property of the `$scope.values` object.

**If this is not what you were after, let me know.**

Comment: So this isn't exactly what I was after, but I did add "controller: 'myController'," to my code and it that fixed it. I guess I have to explicitly state the controller used within the directive. I'll read up on it. Thanks!

Comment: Be careful with allowing too many directives having direct access to the application level controller. It seems like an easy thing to do but it starts making all of your directives into a lovely plate of spaghetti with meatballs.